# Find and replace NA values with value of adjacent field in a new data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I am trying to replace NA value in `asdate` column with the values in `asdate1`.

```
asdate1    asdate   Expected result
0014-09-09  09/09/14    09/09/14
0014-09-09  09/09/14    09/09/14
16/10/14    <NA>    16/10/14
16/10/14    <NA>    16/10/14
30/10/13    <NA>    30/10/13
28/01/14    <NA>    28/01/14
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
asdate3<-data.frame()

While (i < len(asdate)) {
    if (asdate == "NA") {
        asdate3 = asdate1  
    } else {
        (asdate = asdate3)
    }
}
```

Comment: make a reproducible data,

Comment: If these a *real* `NA` values, just do `indx <- is.na(df$asdate) ; df$asdate[indx] <- df$asdate1[indx]`

Comment: Thanks David. these are real NA values. When i do a is.na on asdate i get the last 3 values as false

Comment: sorry David. my bad. i meant to type, i get the last the 3 values as TRUE when i do a is.na on asdate

Comment: So my solution should work then, unless `asdate` is a factor

Comment: this is what i get > indx<-is.na(df2$asdate) ; df2$asdate[indx] <-df2$asdate1[indx]
> head(indx)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

Comment: Why `head(indx)`? `indx` is just, well, an index... do `head(df2$asdate)`...

Comment: David...you're awesome! that worked